# Prawnto doesn't work with Rails 4.1.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, prawn, prawnto

I have worked with prawnto before and it works great. But when I use it again today, I got this error:

```
uninitialized constant ActionView::CompiledTemplates::Prawn
```

and the code is just

show.html.erb

```
 pdf.text "Hello World"
```

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: What did you change between the time it was working and the time when it was not working?

Comment: No, It's a completely different application, which used Rails 4.0.1.

Comment: What version of rails did the previous application use?  And. . . are you talking about this gem here: https://github.com/prior/prawnto ?  It hasn't been updated in 6 years, it may be a bit difficult to find someone who knows anything about it.  If you want to proceed we're going to need more information.  What have you done to try to resolve the problem so far?  What hasn't worked?

Comment: There is also this version of prawnto which has had some more recent attention: https://github.com/GetJobber/prawnto .  Are you using this one?

Comment: Sorry for inactivity, the electricity was down. By the way, the gem that you mentioned works great, thanks @Ecnalyr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a version of [Prawnto](https://github.com/prior/prawnto) that hasn't been updated in about 6 years.

You should switch to this version of the gem: [prawnto_2](https://github.com/GetJobber/prawnto)

Comment: By the way, `prawnto_2` is dependent on the old `prawnto` so I need to install both. Thanks.